# How to set bottom edge to CardView as Fab shape in BottomAppBar?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would make an insert `FAB` in my `CardView` like the one set by default in the `BottomAppBar`.

I changed my `CardView` to `MaterialCardView` to change the bottom edge bu setting the `BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment`

The issue is that i'm playing with the fabMargin, roundedCornerRadius, cradleVerticalOffset and fabDiameter but i can't set it's values to get the result from the native BottomAppBar inset FAB.

so which values should i set in it?

Desired behaviour would be like this (Actual picture of my BottomAppBar):

[image]

While i get this (Actual picture of my CardView):

[image]

My FAB code looks like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnScan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nuovo_documento"
    android:translationY="-36dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/cardView"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_outline_qr_code_scanner"
    app:tint="@color/white" />
```

And the code where i set the shape to the Card is the following:

```kotlin
val bottomAppBarTreatment = BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment(16f, 2f, 8f)
bottomAppBarTreatment.fabDiameter = 110f

cardView.shapeAppearanceModel = cardView.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
    .setBottomEdge(bottomAppBarTreatment)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnScan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationY="24dp"
    ../>
```

and:

```
val bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment = BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment(
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.margin),  //5dp
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.rounded_corner),  //8dp
    resources.getDimension(R.dimen.vertical_offset)  //0dp
)
bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment.fabDiameter = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.diameter)  //56dp

cardView.shapeAppearanceModel = cardView.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
   .setTopEdge(bottomAppBarTreatment)
   .build()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using below code snippet to achive this result using background image like below.

[image]

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rr_fab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_bottom_nav"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_top"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_last"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:foreground="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:foreground="@android:color/transparent">
                    
                    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fac_home"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_10"
                        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/home" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_bottom_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/padding_50"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cut_nav_full_another_grey_two"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10"
            app:layout_behavior="com.wpa3.productshopify.widget.BottomNavigationViewBehavior">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_category"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.2"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/category"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/category"
                android:textColor="@color/gray71"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orders"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/order"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/track_your_order"
                android:textColor="@color/gray71"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_profile"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.5"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/profile"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/my_account"
                android:textColor="@color/gray71"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_more"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/more"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/more"
                android:textColor="@color/gray71"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Background Image = https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAVJl.jpg

Hope this may helps you.